# Connect to cqlsh cassandra cluster running in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra

We have three node Cassandra cluster spinned up in Kubernetes.

```
$ kubectlget pods
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
k8-cluster-0             1/1     Running   0          6d4h
k8-cluster-1             1/1     Running   0          6d4h
k8-cluster-2             1/1     Running   0          6d4h
```

Built a load balancer on top of this

```
$ kubectl get service
NAME                          TYPE           CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                                       AGE   
cassandra-dse-port            LoadBalancer   1.2.3.4          10.11.12.13  9042:31791/TCP,7000:30071/TCP,7001:30114/TCP,7199:31043/TCP   4h38m
```

I am able to connect to `cqlsh` by executing in pod. But how do I connect to cluster from local?
like which ip i need to mention to connect to `cqlsh`

Comment: This cluster is in Cloud Provider or Local env? Is it possible to provide your configuration yamls? Did you follow any tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

You can use kubectl port-forward command to expose it your localhost.

Checkout [this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/)

You can expose it via pod or service name ...